# Some images of folder do not get displayed on web page

Tags: html, image

On my webpage www.example.com I display images next to texts. Some pictures of the folder "minipics" are not getting displayed.

Path in HTML:

```
<img src="minipics/m_5b56aa7040b4f1224ee19c17b6f73ab1.jpg" alt="">
```

However: Opening the image directly in the browser via "www.example.com/minipics/m_5b56aa7040b4f1224ee19c17b6f73ab1.jpg" works!

What is strange: When I after having opened the picture directly via the absolute path (as described above) reload the page on which I expect the images to show up, the picture that I just opened directly gets displayed. But only this picture, NOT the other ones.

Only some pictures that are contained in the folder "minipics" do not get displayed. For example, those pictures uploaded via a new picture upload do get displayed.

Can anybody see a solution to this problem?

Comment: Can you show us the surrounding HTML and any relevant CSS so we can get a better idea?

Answer (score 0):

you can try to add a slash ( **/** ) to the file path.
In your url the folder is in the document root. If your file isn't, this can help.

```
<img src="/minipics/m_5b56aa7040b4f1224ee19c17b6f73ab1.jpg" alt="">
```

Answer (score 0):

If your folder structure is like below

- index.html
- minipics

  - m_5b56aa7040b4f1224ee19c17b6f73ab1.jpg

Then change the code to below

`<img src="./minipics/m_5b56aa7040b4f1224ee19c17b6f73ab1.jpg" alt="">`

**./** means current folder.

Hope this will help you.